# How to use Selenium Server to run to playback from Selenium Builder

Tags: java, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am using nightwatch.js and selenium to test my application web, i    tried a lot of solution in the net, but always the same errors :

```
D:\nightwatch\node_modules\nightwatch\lib>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2
.53.0.jar
18:42:37.363 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
18:42:37.440 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.92-b14
18:42:37.441 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
18:42:37.448 INFO - v2.53.0, with Core v2.53.0. Built from revision  35ae25b
18:42:37.492 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
18:42:37.493 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not re gistered
18:42:37.499 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=,platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform VISTA
18:42:37.500 INFO - Driver class not found: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
18:42:37.501 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver is not registered
18:42:37.598 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to:http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
18:42:37.599 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

Comment: have you downloaded the selenium driver for Opera? Have you tried to run it with a different browser? E.g. Chrome (you will need to download a driver for this), Firefox (driver comes with Selenium)

Comment: I didn't download the driver opera, because I don't use it, I tested with chrome driver but generates me compiler errors

Comment: i try with safari but its not work, with chromedriver its done, but when i run the server: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar i got the same errors